# Github Pages - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: git, github, node-modules, font-awesome, github-pages

I'm trying to have my "font-awesome" icons showing on my Github Pages, but as you can see it does not work.

Here is the
[ERRORS I GOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v5Ch.png)

Here is the Github repo :
[MY REPO](https://github.com/darki0ni/portfolio)

Here is the Github Page :
[MY GH PAGE](https://darki0ni.github.io/portfolio/)

I added my "node-modules" directory to my .gitignore file on the advice of some guy that is known to be very good in IT but it obviously didn't work so I re-added them but it's still not showing at all...

Is that a problem with github pages ? because it works super fine when I host my website on localhost and I can access "node-modules" directory from my github repo.

Also, if u guys see any major security flaws/breach, please tell me :( !

I'm new to this !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host the fontawesome files yourself, you need to include them in a folder that will be picked up by GitHub Pages. GitHub pages seems to have [excluded the `node_modules` folder automatically](https://github.com/darki0ni/portfolio/actions/runs/4337150567/jobs/7572960441#step:4:35) (`EntryFilter: excluded /node_modules`).
That means creating another folder like `assets` or something comparable should be picked up by GitHub Pages and can then be referenced on your site. There is also some more info on how to include fontawesome for self-hosting in the [fontawesome docs](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts).

In general using a framework instead of raw html/css makes things like this a lot easier. You seem to use npm but since your npm does not actually compile the code for you, it does not bake the fontawesome files into your scripts in any way.

You could take a look at react or vue as general modern frameworks for creating websites or move to a full site generation tool like gatsby, jekyll, or mkdocs to make creation even easier - all of these of course still allow you to fully customize the pages but make the annoying parts like dependencies and boilderplate elements a lot easier. There are also a lot of amazing templates to kickstart a new site, especially portfolio site are very popular!